# How to load a gradle project and then use that as a dependency in one of the existing projects in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jitpack

I have a gradle zip file that I want to use as a dependency in my project in intelliJ.

So I opened that project using Open and then pointing to build.gradle file. Tried to run it and got `Could not find or load main class`.

How to solve this and then also how to add this project to some other project as a dependency in IntelliJ.

I am fairly new to IntelliJ and Java project settings, will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A ZIP file? That sounds unusual. What does the ZIP file contain?

Comment: @dnault: a gradle project. So I want to add https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg/releases/tag/0.2.0 as a dependency in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers of that project have chosen to promote JitPack as the way to consume their JARs. You can tell because their [Github project page](https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg) has a little "JitPack" badge at the top of the readme. If you click on that badge, it takes you to [this page](https://jitpack.io/#Netflix/iceberg/0.2.0) showing how to add the dependency to your Gradle or Maven project.

If you're not yet using Maven or Gradle, this is a great opportunity to learn :-)

- [Gradle Java tutorial](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html)
- [Maven tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

When you open your Maven or Gradle project in IntelliJ, it will automatically resolve the dependencies for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped.

Comment: Quick question: So I was able to import as `import com.netflix.iceberg.Table;` but I see I am not able to import some of the packages like `import com.netflix.iceberg.spark`. here is the entire package list I expect to be available after adding dependencies: https://netflix.github.io/iceberg/current/javadoc/index.html?com/netflix/iceberg/Table.html

Comment: @Atihska The Iceberg project is made up of several libraries. Try adding a dependency on the 'iceberg-spark' artifact? Full list of modules is in [this section of the readme](https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg#building).

Answer (score 1):

To add it as a dependency you can use this [this](https://jitpack.io/#Netflix/iceberg/0.2.0)

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Mamaev. This helped.